# Multitouch (Multiple Touch Events at Once) in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, multi-touch

I am creating an app in corona that has a button to shoot, reload, and a joystick to move the character around. I want the user to be able to shoot while he/she and be moving the character with the joystick simultaneously. I tried using Corona's built-in multitouch:

```
system.activate("multitouch")
```

but it does not seem to have any affect.

Does anyone have any ideas to how I can make the multitouch work, or any other ideas of how I should approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine, you are registering event listener on "touch" event:

```
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchManager)
```

In this event, you have event id, which is differs for different touches during multitap. Here's a part of my code which allows user to move and fire at the same time.

```
 local function touchManager(event)
        if (event.id == ignore_event_id)  then return;  end; -- should protect when user fired, and the same event messes with joystick
         -- ....
 end
```